# VMware Fusion raw disk "Missing operating system" error for dual-boot system (Host OS 10.8.2 & Guest Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, vmware-fusion, ubuntu-12.10, refit, macbook-pro-retina

I am trying to set up a virtual machine in VMware Fusion to boot the Ubuntu 12.10 install from another partition on my main disk. I followed standard instructions for creating raw disks, but I get a "Missing operating system" error on booting the VM (after authenticating for raw disk access). It's possible that this problem is not actually with VMware, but I'm not sure how to move forward.

Here's the output of "diskutil list". Note that partitions 4 and 5 are ext-4 as formatted by the Ubuntu installer

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            80.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         45.0 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data                         364.9 GB   disk0s5
   6:                 Linux Swap                         9.2 GB     disk0s6
```

I use rEFIt on my mac to boot natively into the Ubuntu partition (/dev/disk0s4).

I created the raw disk to point to disk0, partition 4, lsilogic (as seems to be recommended in related posts). The complete output of the rawdiskCreator print command is below. I am not sure why partitions 5 and 6 are not listed

```
Nr      Start       Size Type Id Sytem                   
-- ---------- ---------- ---- -- ------------------------
 1          1     409639 BIOS EE Unknown
 2     409640  156250000 BIOS AF HFS+
 3  156659640    1269536 BIOS AF HFS+
 4  157929176   87890624 BIOS 83 Linux
```

The commands I used to create the raw disk are below. Note that I created the rawdisk in the same directory as the VM's .vmx file

```
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-rawdiskCreator create /dev/disk0 4 vmware_rawdisk_ubuntu lsilogic
sudo chown <username> vmware_rawdisk_ubuntu
```

I then edited an existing VM .vmx file to point to this device, removing the existing drive and adding the lines:

```
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
scsi0:0.fileName = "vmware_rawdisk_ubuntu.vmdk"
```

I mostly used the following as references. #1 to set up dual-boot and #2 to set up the raw disk. #3 actually mentions the problem I have (or a similar one) but the solution did not work for me (search "Missing operating system")

1. "Install Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal on MacBook Pro 10,1 (Retina)"
2. "Using raw disks/partitions from VMWare Fusion"
3. "Multibooting Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X on a Mac and using them as Virtual Machines"

Note: The disk is a SATA device. [This link](http://communities.vmware.com/message/351842) claims that you can't use SATA devices as raw disks, but there appears to be a bit of confusion on the accuracy of that claim.